# List is working but post is not working in nested serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, serialization

This is my code:

Models.py

```
class Kitchen(models.Model):
kitchen_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
state = models.CharField(max_length = 40, )
city = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.kitchen_name


class AssignAudit(models.Model):
kitchen = models.ForeignKey(Kitchen, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
assigned_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
assigned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null =  True, related_name = 'assigned_audits')

class KitchenAudit(models.Model):
assign_audit = models.ForeignKey(AssignAudit, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
total_images = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
marks_scored = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
comment = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class KitchenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Kitchen
    fields = '__all__'

class AssignAuditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
kitchen = KitchenSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = AssignAudit
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    assign_audit = AssignAudit.objects.create(**validated_data)        
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    for question in questions:
        kitchen_audit = KitchenAudit.objects.create(question=question,assign_audit=assign_audit)
        for images in range(question.no_of_images):
            KitchenAuditImage.objects.create(kitchen_audit=kitchen_audit)
    return assign_audit
```

Views.py

```
class AssignAuditSerializerListCreate(ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = AssignAuditSerializer
queryset = AssignAudit.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response({'audit_assign':serializer.data})
```

I want to combine both of my table above to display it in one API using django-rest-framework. GET method is working fine but when i am doing POST method, it's saying i have to provide kitchen value.

```
{
    "kitchen": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the KitchenAudit model as well ?

Comment: Hi @matthieu.cham. I have edited the question. Please refer to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `read_only = True` that's why it is ignoring kitchen while posting, put or patch. It is clearly read_only so you cannot post to it.

As an alternative, you can override get_serializer_class() function in view to make this happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is to make `kitchen` as read-only.

```
kitchen = KitchenSerializer(read_only=True)
```

Comment: While performing POST it is getting inserted but kitchen column of assign audit model becomes null.

Comment: you need to manually add that when you can `kitchen_audit ` response from `KitchenAudit.objects.create`.

Comment: kitchen Id is passed via POST request and it is processed at the first line `assign_audit = AssignAudit.objects.create(**validated_data)` of the AssignAuditSerializer create function. I'm not sure how do you want me to handle that.